# Make pair from row/column data of Python DataFrame again

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to change below dataframe to dataframe that remarks some pairs like this:
Is that possible? if so, could you share how I can make this or which concept do I need to find.

Thanks in advance

From :

```
x    a    b    c    d    e    f    g   label
1  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0     0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0     0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0     1.0
```

To :

```
x tag label
1  a    0.0
2  f    0.0
3  d    1.0
```

Comment: Try df.dot(df.columns)

Comment: Assuming `x` is your index: `pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :-1].idxmax(1), df['label']],1)`

Comment: @rafaelc x is not index, x is one of variable. Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `concat` with `idxmax`:

```
print (pd.concat([df["x"],df.iloc[:,1:-1].idxmax(axis=1),df["label"]],axis=1))

#
   x  0  label
0  1  a    0.0
1  2  f    0.0
2  3  d    1.0
```